# Incremental builds in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

How can i turn on incremental builds in VS2010? I've noticed that my project rebuild everything each time i press build. Is there any option in VS to turn this on? Or should i modify *.csproj on my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projects should build incrementally already (just make sure that you do `Build` instead of `Rebuild`). The best way to check if incremental building works is to run the build from the command line. The second time you build it should take almost no time.

If things are still getting rebuilt, then perhaps you've modified your projects in some way that's messing up with the build order. Looking at the build logs (via the `/v` option) can help you poinpoint what's going on.

Comment: The TrackFileAccess property can mess with incremental builds. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.tasks.generateresource.trackfileaccess.aspx